# ¿Como hago que mi código muestre los cambios de ambos campos?

Tags: javascript

Este codigo lo fui armando con partes de otro, Yo quiero generar un código que depende de campos (`select` y un `input`)... y  quiero que se actualice cuando haga un cambio en el `select` o el `input`, mi código solo muestra el cambio cuando actualizo en `select` pero no el `input`.

```js
var valueSelect = function(foo){
  var ident = document.getElementById('ident').value
  document.getElementById('comida').value = "CMMC-"+foo+"-"+ident;
};
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <select name="seleccion" onchange="valueSelect(this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML);"> 
    <option value="0">Seleccionar.</option>
    <option value="1">Cuatro</option>
    <option value="2">Arpa</option>
    <option value="3">Maraca</option>
    <option value="4">Guitarra</option>
    <option value="5">Mandolina</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="ident" id="ident"/>   
  <input type="text" name="comida" id="comida" value="" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que estás capturando el valor del `input` cuando el `select` cambia del valor, cuando haces eso el valor del `input` aún es vacío por eso no te concatena nada, entonces se debe asignar otro evento `change` pero esta vez al `input`:

```js
var ident = '', seleccion = '';

var valueSelect = function(foo){
  seleccion = foo;
  
  document.getElementById('comida').value = "CMMC-"+seleccion+"-"+ident;
};

function valueInput(valor){
  ident = valor;

  document.getElementById('comida').value = "CMMC-"+seleccion+"-"+ident;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <select name="seleccion" onchange="valueSelect(this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML);"> 
    <option value="0">Seleccionar.</option>
    <option value="1">Cuatro</option>
    <option value="2">Arpa</option>
    <option value="3">Maraca</option>
    <option value="4">Guitarra</option>
    <option value="5">Mandolina</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="ident" id="ident"/ onchange="valueInput(this.value)">
  <input type="text" name="comida" id="comida" value="" />
</form>
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es muy útil, pero cuando vuelvo a realizar un cambio en el select, se desaparece el valor anterior... yo quiero que se mantengan se vean los cambios por así decirlo en tiempo real...  ¿No hay otra forma de lograr eso?

Comment: @JesusSandinoRodrguezFiguera ok, con cual de las dos opciones lo estás haciendo? supongo que la primera, por que en la segunda no pasa eso

Comment: Si la primera, porque en la segunda supongamos que también haga un cambio pero en input, no se visualiza tampoco.

Comment: @JesusSandinoRodrguezFiguera listo, ya he actualizado el ejemplo

Comment: @JesusSandinoRodrguezFiguera borré el segundo ejemplo por que independiente de la forma es necesario tener el evento change en ambos campos